# Rearrange fullscreen windows in macOS

Tags: macos, window-manager, fullscreen

I have a few fullscreen windows opened. I can use a trackpad gesture to navigate through them. But to rearrange them, I have to exit fullscreen on some windows and enter fullscreen on them again, but this can take a long time. Is there a short or easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slide up on your trackpad with three fingers. On the top, you should see a bar containing `Desktop` and any other fullscreen windows you have opened. Drag those to rearrange them.

If you go back by sliding down with three fingers, you should find that the windows have been rearranged.